# Unity 2D Mouse Zoom, but zoom in to location of mouse point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zooming, mouse

Edit : I need an answer for a 2D implementation, not 3D. So the 'Asked Before' question doesn't work for my project.

Edit : Using the accepted answer below, this is my working script. It's slightly off because the 0.1F part of the Vector3 is hard to get right, but it works. Time.deltaTime didn't work though.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{

private float zoom = 10;
Vector3 newPosition;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0 && zoom > 9)
    {
        zoom -= 1;
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = zoom;
        newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, 0.1F);
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0 && zoom < 101)
    {
        zoom += 1;
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = zoom;
    }

}

}
```

Original Question : I have a basic script for zooming in and out, but when I zoom back in with the mouse-wheel, I want to zoom in to the point of the mouse cursor. I think you can see something similar in the Paradox Games (EU4 etc), where you zoom out, hold your mouse over a country off to the left of the screen, then zoom in and the country zooms in and becomes centered.

Here's my basic script so far, attached to my camera, which just zooms in and out in a straight line.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour {

public float zoom = 10F;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0 && zoom > 9)
    {
        zoom -= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0 && zoom < 101)
    {
        zoom += 1;
    }

    GetComponent<Camera>().orthographicSize = zoom;

  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the 'Asked Before' answer is that it's for a 3D implementation and I need 2D. It works (I think) by transforming the position of the camera but I think I need to do something with 'orthographicsize' for 2D.

Comment: Did not mark as a duplicate but the duplicate should also work as-well

Comment: It doesn't. In fact, the duplicate does nothing at all because it moves the camera transform, which I believe does nothing in 2D. The 2D version requires a change in the orthographic size of the camera. My solution is ok, but not perfect. On the assumption that people come here looking for the same solution, the duplicate shouldn't be marked as the correct answer because it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Ok. Note that I did not mark as a duplicate but since the duplicate did not work for you, I reopened it.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to ask if there's a way to remove the suggestion that the duplicate gives the correct answer when it doesn't, because any new Unity programmer (e.g me) will be lost. The answers below are along the right lines and my attempt above to get it working does vaguely achieve the desired result (but not perfect). Tinkering around with the Vector3.Lerp (the z value) gives various results, but none seem spot on.

Comment: Sadly I don't know the exact effect you are shooting for but Umair's answer is on point. Maybe if you upload video/animated gif of the zoom from the paradox game and your current effect, I will see if I can help

Comment: The camera is drifting constantly with Umair's answer. I want it to only zoom in when I mouse-wheel scroll and otherwise I don't want the view to follow the mouse, which it's doing. Also it wasn't actually zooming to the point correctly, but changing Time.deltaTime to 0.1F gave a reasonable result. But it's fine, the result I have now is acceptable and I've added his as the best answer and put my new script above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but I hope this will work.

```
Vector3 newPosition;
bool canZoom;
bool isMoving;

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0 && zoom > 9)
    {
        zoom -= 1;
        canZoom = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0 && zoom < 101)
    {
        zoom += 1;
        canZoom = true;
    }

     if (canZoom) 
     {
        isMoving = true;
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = zoom;
        newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
     }
     if (isMoving)
     {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position,  newPosition, Time.deltaTime);
     }

     if(transform.position == newPosition)
     {
         isMoving = false;
     }

}
```

Note: If you want the camera to maintain certain camera height, adjust newPosision's y value before moving.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The math seems to be correct and it appears to be working, the only problem is that once you start scrolling, it scrolls permanently and is hard to control. I'm trying to fix it, but I think the basic idea is right.

Comment: This was intended to put you in the track. Please accept the answer. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the difference in world space and move towards it while zooming.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour {

public float zoom = 10F;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0 && zoom > 9)
    {
        zoom -= 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0 && zoom < 101)
    {
        zoom += 1;
    }

     Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
     RaycastHit hit;
     Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
     Vector3 targetPos;

     if (Physics.Raycast(ray , out hit))
     {
        targetPos = hit.point;
     }
```

<s>Camera cam = GetComponent();</s>

```
    cam.orthographicSize = zoom;
    cam.transform.position += (targetPos - transform.position) / 5f;

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Unity, getting a couple of errors. The 2nd use of 'Camera Cam' I think just needs to be removed as it's already declared. But I'm getting an error on the final line on 'targetPos', it says 'Use of unassigned local variable targetPos'. I don't get how it's unassigned as it's just been assigned above....

Comment: Correct, I updated the answer.

"targetPos" is not assigned, whenever the raycast won't hit. You could put the last line inside the if-block. 
However try to Debug.Log in the else-part to see that you are not hitting something.

The mouse needs to be hovering an object with collider for the raycast to work. Do you have a terrain or something?